# Facebook Tabs - Difference between apps vs tabs

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-tabs

I have recently inherited the Admin/developer role for our page and I am new to Facebook Development. I am attempting to add a new tab to our page and the only option I am getting is to build an App but all of the App options I come across make it sound like it's trying to do more than what I want it to do.

What I want to do is produce a tab on the page. That will link to an app/canvas displaying an image that the user can click to go to our offer.

So far I've built a basic app with Display Name, namespace, Page Tab Name, Page Tab URL and a Tab image. but when I refresh my page I do not get a new tab and when I preview the app page it is not the format I am looking for.

I've tried going through the tutorials but since this is all new to me I ahve yet to make any sense as to what I'm looking for or missing. Could anyone let me know what app format I am looking for? Or am I in the wrong place entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly add an app to a page. Not sure if you've tried it or not but navigate to:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&display=popup&next=YOUR_PAGE_TAB_URL

Replacing YOUR_APP_ID with your app id and YOUR_PAGE_TAB_URL with the url you set for you page tab.